# Writing unit tests for asp.net web applications

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing

How to write unit tests, integration tests for asp.net web applications ( not an MVC application). Can some one give me help to start up. i am new to this..

Comment: Not to be too much of a downer but you're in for some pain. ASP.NET is very difficult to test. It's a major reason why they came out with MVC, which has testability as a major focus.

Comment: Many years ago I was using http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net but as asp.net advanced the nunitasp framework became outdated and now no longer supported/worked on.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think all this unit testability hype is totally overblown. You can test an ASP.NET application (that is well architected) very easily. We used to call it a "smoke test". Every action that can be done in the app is tested by QA with the idea of breaking something. Usually they will succeed, and the developers get to work to fix it. Just my 2 cents.

A lot of the unit tests I've seen simply represent somebody who can't see the forest for the trees writing a bunch of extra code and layers of stuff that may not be that relevant.

Comment: 1. Not everyone has a QA department. 2. QA-ready code already has extra layers of complexity added to it that unit tested code need not have. Do people sometimes stink at writing unit tests? Sure, but it's pretty bad logic to say that that's a good reason to never write them.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment. I've seen many cases where the QA write bad tests, tests that actually test very little, too high-level tests (find-to-fix time is really bad), etc. You really do wanna have tests. It will almost always save you time and improve your overall website.